# Why does Django IntegerField converts unicode to str before converting to int?

Tags: python, django

I looked at [Django's code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cecbb71312a5cc515ac1ddf821bdeb072c3bfaea/django/forms/fields.py#L265) for `IntegerField`'s `to_python` method. The type conversion part is

```
    try:
        value = int(str(value))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'], code='invalid')
```

The code converts `value` (type unicode) to `str` first and then `int`. Why can't it be cast to `int` directly i.e.

```
    try:
        value = int(value)
    except...
```

Comment: Because `value` may be an object, not just a string literal. Calling `str` will force its string representation, rather than its `repr`. Also, consider _"Explicit is better than implicit"_ from the Zen of Python.

Comment: An object in Python is represented naturally as garbage. It will show up as something like <myfile.object instance at 0x38DF32>. This cannot be converted to an integer. Objects that represent numbers most often have handlers such as __ unicode __, or an overrided repr, that return a *representation* of that object. These usually print as a more reasonable value, such as the true value of the object (a number, hopefully). Of course this is not always the case, but the str() value of an object usually gives something closer to the true value of an object. It's hard to explain, I hope this helps!